# In android IF OR block is evaluated even if first block evaluates to true

Tags: java, android

Getting crash for below code. It seems in android the IF OR block is getting evaluated even if first block evaluates to "true".

```
TileItem ti=null;
...
// code which initialises reference ti 

if (ti == null || !ti.isValid()){
    ...
}
```

In a function block I am initialising object of TileItem to ti, then doing some operation if `ti` is not null and is valid. `idvalid()` is validating some properties of the TileItem object. But I am getting crash and crash log says

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean xxx.TileItem.isValid()' on a null object reference

I can't figure out the problem here, is anybody have came across the problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

The code is entirely correct

```
if (ti == null || !ti.isValid()) { ... }
```

The null pointer exception must concern something else; for instance inside `isValid`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> Conditional-Or Operator || 
> At run time, the left-hand operand
>   expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is
>   subjected to unboxing conversion. 
> If the resulting value is
>   true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the
>   right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.

So if `ti` is `null` then `!ti.isValid()` is not evaluated so there would be no problem.  
 But if `ti` is not `null` then `!ti.isValid()` but it wouldn't throw NPE because `ti` is not `null`.
So maybe the exception is thrown somewhere else.